# Setter is not triggered when object changed through ngModel

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following code:

```
set dynamicData(val) {
        this.editableData.emit(val);
}

get dynamicData() {
    return this.formsData;
}
```

If i set `dynamicData` value from my component, the setter is triggered.
But if i set `dynamicData` from input with `[(ngModel)]` the actual value of `dynamicData` is changed, but the setter is not triggered for some reason.

Here's the input:

```
<input type="text" name="dynamicDataSender"
                   *ngIf="someCondition"
                   [(ngModel)]="dynamicData.sender"/>
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: That is because you're setting `dynamicData.sender`, not `dynamicData` itself. The change is to `dynamicData`'s inner property, which means the getter is called instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[(ngModel)]` syntax can only set a data-bound property. If you need to do something more or something different, you can write the expanded form.

```
 <input type="text" name="dynamicDataSender" #ref
   *ngIf="someCondition"  [ngModel]="dynamicData.sender" (ngModelChange)="dynamicData(ref.value)"/>
```

The `ngModel` data property sets the element's value property and the `ngModelChange` event property listens for changes to the element's value
 `ngModelChange` will be fired on every keystroke you need to debounce value else event will be emitted for every keystroke and To debounce values you can use a `Subject`. A `subject` is both an `observable` and an `observer`. This means you can treat it as an observable and pass values to it as well.

```
debouncer= new Subject();
  constructor() {


   this. debouncer
    .debounceTime(1000)
    .subscribe((val) =>{ 
      console.log(val);
      this.editableData.emit(val);

    });
  }

set dynamicData(val) {
         this.debouncer.next(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You reference `[(ngModel)]="dynamicData.sender"` instead of `dynamicData`. You should reference the object.

If dynamicData needs to be an event emitter, then you should not use it as a property bind, but instead, use an `(onChange)="modelChanged($event)"` handler, where you can emit the new values to the dynamicData. ( `modelChanged(value){this.dynamicData.emit(value);}` ) and use some other property as ngModel.